# How to test Custom Hook that throws Error on render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks-testing-library

I have a custom hook that throws error if condition is met when executing Hook. I want to test that the error is thrown, so test should pass if error is thrown.

I tried wrapping Hook in an `Error Boundary`, but the result.error is undefined. So how can I test that the error is thrown with `react-hooks-testing-library`?

```
test('it should not be possible to group values by week', () => {
    // Arrange
    const registrations = registrations
    const startDate = moment('2019-11-01')
    const endDate = moment('2019-11-30')
    const groupBy = GroupBy.Week

    // Act
    const { result } = renderHook(
        () => useSingleValueChartData(registrations, startDate, endDate, groupBy),
        { wrapper: AppErrorBoundary }
    )
    // this passes but I would rather test that result.error was defined
    expect(result.error).not.toBeDefined()
})
```